# What is a good model for regression problem with binary features and small data?

Tags: models, regression

I am trying to predict the solution time for riddles in which matchsticks are combined into digits and operators. An example of a matchstick riddle is 4-2=8. The solution for this riddle would be obtained by moving one matchstick from the ‘8’ to the ‘-’ sign, resulting in the correct equation 4+2=6. The data consists of 100 riddles and the corresponding solution times. The two types of features that are available for each riddle are:

- a 23 dimensional binary vector that indicates which of the available positions are filled with matches
  or
- a 12-dimensional integer vector that counts the appearance of each token (10 digits, 2 operators)

Although today neural nets are very popular I am not sure that a neural net is the best choice for this particular problem. Firstly, because the data set is very small. Secondly because of the binary inputs.  What might be a more effective model for this problem ?